# Split by : but not ::

Tags: java, regex

I was wondering how I could split a String by `:` but not `::` using `String#split(String)`

I am using Java if it makes a difference.

I looked around a lot and I couldn't find anything, and I'm not familiar with Regex...

Example:
`coolKey:cool::value` should return `["coolKey", "cool::value"]`
`cool::key:cool::value` should return `["cool::key", "cool::value"]`

Comment: Regex look ahead and look behind would solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try splitting on `(?<!:):(?!:)`:

```
String input = "cool::key:cool::value";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<!:):(?!:)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This prints:

```
[cool::key, cool::value]
```

The regex used here says to split when:

```
(?<!:)    the character which precedes is NOT colon
:         split on colon
(?!:)     which is also NOT followed by colon
```